# Adding new DNS record to Netlify in order to make my domain point a new site

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, dns-servers, netlify

I have a new site: **newsite.com** (my new site has no subdomain such as www or ftp), so I wrote "@" to Name section when I created my DNS record.

I had an old site that I wanted to redo. I registered a domain name on Netlify for this: **www.myPurchasedDomain.net**. So my DNS records look like this:

**myPurchasedDomain.net** | 3600 IN NETLIFY | **oldSiteAdress.app.netlify**
**www.myPurchasedDomain.net** | 3600 IN NETLIFY | **oldSiteAdress.app.netlify**

Now I added my new address that I want:

[image]

and I deleted the old ones and now this is my DNS records:

[image]

When I go to as-quebec.net, no site appears.

So, **myPurchasedDomain.net** is still pointing to **oldSiteAdress.app.netlify** and I would like to point to this address: **newsite.com**.

What should I do more? Delete the old ones? Can I keep it? But if I keep it, how can Netlify know that I want to point on this: **newsite.com**?

Like I said, my domain is still pointing to **oldSiteAdress.netlify.app**. I want that it points to newsite.com, but how could I do that? What I added in the DNS records (CNAME of my new site) doesn't do the job, so what did I miss?

Netlify is handling the DNS for my domain **as-quebec.net** and **as-quebec.netlify.app**. My new address: **mathdx-001-site1.etempurl.com** was created by myasp.net. I want that **as-quebec.net** points to **mathdx-001-site1.etempurl.com** and that **as-quebec.net** will no more point to **as-quebec.netlify.app**.

Is CNAME the right choice for my purpose?